# Checking history of deleted folders using Tortoise CVS

Tags: cvs, tortoisecvs

We are using Tortoise CVS which is quite new for me. We have deleted a bunch of folders from repository using Tortoise CVS (CVS remove and CVS commit from Tortoise CVS).

Now I want to check the version number of this commit. I can find the version if there is some update on a file by clicking on CVS history of that particular file. But I am not able to figure out how to find the version of the revision for Deleted folders. I tried to click on Web log but did not get anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CVS does not keep revision information for folders. It only keeps track of individual files.